# Search not working using recyclerview - Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

Hello I am trying to do a search by the name of the user the data is in a recyclerview where all users are listed but when writing nothing happens how can I fix it? I believe I am doing something very wrong but I really don't know how to make it work.

I saw some tutorials on the internet but I couldn't implement

```
public class FindFriendsActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private RecyclerView FindFriendsRecyclerList;
    private DatabaseReference UsersRef;
    private MaterialSearchView searchView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_friends);


        UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");


        FindFriendsRecyclerList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.find_friends_recycler_list);
        FindFriendsRecyclerList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.find_friends_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Find Friends");
        searchView = findViewById(R.id.materialSearchPrincipal);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new MaterialSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {





                return true;
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Contacts> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Contacts>()
                .setQuery(UsersRef, Contacts.class)
                .build();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Contacts, FindFriendViewHolder> adapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Contacts, FindFriendViewHolder>(options) {
                    @Override
                    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FindFriendViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull Contacts model)
                    {
                        holder.userName.setText(model.getName());
                        holder.userStatus.setText(model.getStatus());
                        Picasso.get().load(model.getImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.profile_image).into(holder.profileImage);


                        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view)
                            {
                                String visit_user_id = getRef(position).getKey();

                                Intent profileIntent = new Intent(FindFriendsActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                                profileIntent.putExtra("visit_user_id", visit_user_id);
                                startActivity(profileIntent);
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public FindFriendViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i)
                    {
                        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.users_display_layout, viewGroup, false);
                        FindFriendViewHolder viewHolder = new FindFriendViewHolder(view);
                        return viewHolder;
                    }
                };

        FindFriendsRecyclerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        adapter.startListening();
    }



    public static class FindFriendViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView userName, userStatus;
        CircleImageView profileImage;


        public FindFriendViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);

            userName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_profile_name);
            userStatus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_status);
            profileImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.users_profile_image);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menuPesquisa);
        searchView.setMenuItem(item);

        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: you have to set up the search filter in the adapter, without it cannot work. you should google it, there are several tutorials on blogs and on youtube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search from your `searchView` like this, for example it is searching for matches on `title`

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {

                Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                        .getReference()
                        .child("posts").orderByChild("title").equalTo(s);

                if(s.equals("")){
                    query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                            .getReference()
                            .child("posts");
                }

                fetch(query);

                return false;
            }
        });


private void fetch(Query query) {

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Model> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Model>()
                        .setQuery(query, new SnapshotParser<Model>() {
                            @NonNull
                            @Override
                            public Model parseSnapshot(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                return new Model(snapshot.child("id").getValue().toString(),
                                        snapshot.child("title").getValue().toString(),
                                        snapshot.child("desc").getValue().toString());
                            }
                        })
                        .build();

        adapter = new CustomFirebaseRecylerAdapter<Model, CustomFirebaseRecylerAdapter.ViewHolder>(options);
        adapter.startListening();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

[Find full project source code here](https://github.com/mzc1986/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter)

Comment: thanks for your answer. one question how to fix this 'Model()' has private access in 'android.graphics.ColorSpace.Model' my atual code https://pastebin.com/8C57RJa0 image of the prolem https://i.imgur.com/L6s9Y8B.png thanks in advance.

Comment: it will be a `Model` class based on your data in the database. Please check my model class https://github.com/mzc1986/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter/blob/master/app/src/main/java/example/androidgrid/firebaserecycleradapter/Model.java your's will be something similar